# Google Cloud Storage Joining multiple csv files

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I exported a dataset from Google BigQuery to Google Cloud Storage, given the size of the file BigQuery exported the file as 99 csv files.

However now I want to connect to my GCP Bucket and perform some analysis with Spark, yet I need to join all 99 files into a single large csv file to run my analysis.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

BigQuery splits the data exported into several files if it is [larger than 1GB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_data_into_one_or_more_files). But you can merge these files with the [gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/compose), check [this official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects#_gsutil) to know how to perform object composition with gsutil.

As BigQuery export the files with the same prefix, you can use a wildcard `*` to merge them into one composite object:

`gsutil compose gs://example-bucket/component-obj-* gs://example-bucket/composite-object`

Note that there is a limit (currently 32) to the number of components that can be composed in a single operation.

The downside of this option is that the header row of each `.csv` file will be added in the composite object. But you can avoid this by modifiyng the [`jobConfig`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs) to set the [`print_header` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.extract.printHeader) to `False`.

Here is a Python sample code, but you can use [any other BigQuery Client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries):

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
bucket_name = 'yourBucket'

project = 'bigquery-public-data'
dataset_id = 'libraries_io'
table_id = 'dependencies'

destination_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, 'file-*.csv')
dataset_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id, project=project)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

job_config = bigquery.job.ExtractJobConfig(print_header=False)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location='US',
    job_config=job_config)  # API request

extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print('Exported {}:{}.{} to {}'.format(
    project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri))
```

Finally, remember to compose an empty `.csv` with just the headers row.